# The best method for bulk loading data into Azure DocumentDB collection

Tags: json, azure-cosmosdb, bulk-load

I'm new to Azure and have a lot of MS SQL data we need to migrate to DocumentDB. I've tried the bulk upload but it appears that you can only have one JSON document per load file, this doesn't appear to be very efficient if we've got 100K+ records to load.

I've used MongoDB before and this has the **mongoimport** tool, is there anything similar to this for DocDB?

Also, any documentation pointers on this would be great.

Comment: Documentation/tool recommendation questions are off-topic for StackOverflow. What have you tried? What challenges are you running into,  specifically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few 1st-party (Microsoft developed) options available:

- DocumentDB migration tool allows you to import data in to DocumentDB
  from a variety of sources (incl. JSON files, SQL, etc.):

  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-import-data
- Azure DocumentDB has integration with Data Factory - which can be
  used to connect to a variety of data sources:

  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-azure-documentdb-connector

Comment: The DocumentDB migration tool is flexible and works well but performance is extremely slow, 26mins to upload 68K documents into a collection.